# Edit Displayifs.aspx webpart layout

Tags: form

I am trying to edit the displayifs.aspx page so that the layout can look like this: 
[image: Example of displaysifs layout I would like]

At the moment I only get the option in advanced mode(of sp designer) to do a vertical or horizontal [image: Options for layout] layout of web parts.

Thanks in advance.

Emma

EDIT*** The layout I want the displayifs page web parts to look like:
[image: Webparts display on displayifs page]

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple "views" of the primary data source in the InfoPath form using the InfoPath Designer. You can add a view on the Page Design tab and click on the 'New View' button. You can even copy the fields from the other view by selecting them all, pasting them, and then modifying the ones you want.

```
<WpNs0:BrowserFormWebPart 
          runat="server" 
          DefaultView="ViewOnly" 
          AllowEdit="True" 
          AllowConnect="True" 
          SubmitBehavior="FormDefault" 
          ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ... >
```

In the either *ifs.aspx page you can see in SPD there is a "BrowserFormWebPart". One of the attributes you can specify on this element is DefaultView. When you look at the automatically generated pages, it's not specified at all, and thus defaults to the template's default view out of the box, but you can add it and set which one is displayed.  In this example it's going to show the View, as defined in the InfoPath template, named ViewOnly.

You can edit all three of the *ifs.aspx pages to have them each show a different view. Note that there is another attribute called ListFormMode that can either be ReadOnly or Editable. When it's ReadOnly it forces the controls into a gritty 'flat' mode, so if you don't like that you can replace the controls with calculated fields bound to field values on your view only view instead of databound controls.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I think you have misunderstood the question I haven't got an issue with displaying InfoPath forms on the displaysifs page but I want the webpart displayed in a particular way not the only way sharepoint desiger is letting me(horizontally or vertically). Not all my web parts on the displayifs page are going to be InfoPath forms.